# Making a php software into .exe

Tags: php, windows, exe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert a PHP script into a stand-alone windows executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046675/convert-a-php-script-into-a-stand-alone-windows-executable)

I want to make .exe file of my ERP. How do i convert my software into .exe? I have no idea about it. Its written in php. Can somebody guide me or provide me if you have any tutorial for the same.

Thanks

Comment: So you have a web application written in PHP, and you want to use it as a desktop software?

Comment: Go for another language. Languages such as C++ or Java have native access to more OS stuff than PHP has, but it also depends on your needs.

Comment: You might be able to bundle a lightweight server, PHP stack and run the source through an encoder/obfuscator - then wrap the whole thing in a Windows installer that pops up localhost:xxxx in your browser to start it up.

Comment: Are you talking about [PHP-GTK](http://gtk.php.net/)?

Comment: @ppeterka - maybe its a command-line tool? Maybe he just wants to provide a compiled web app? In any case, it is possible to write GUI programs with PHP with libs like php-gtk. Not really worth the effort, but it is possible.

Comment: @SDC: that is exactly why I asked. Maybe I have dealt with too many weird questions for today, and have absorbed too many "bad juju" from them, as I thought about the worst possible situation...

Comment: @ppeterka, Yup. Written in PHP and wanted to convert it to .exe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a pretty comprehensive list of PHP compilers in the answer to [Convert a PHP script into a stand-alone windows executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046675/convert-a-php-script-into-a-stand-alone-windows-executable/9046775#9046775)

Comment: @Mark Baker: thanks. I am trying it.

Answer (score 0):

There are PHP compilers available, but in truth, if you want to create a compiled Windows .exe file, PHP is the wrong choice of language.

The compilers that do exist (such as [HipHop](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki)) are targetted at a web server environment.

Comment: Not really true. I've compiled console programs with Phalanger without problems and there was no need for a web server whatsoever.

Answer (score -1):

With the advent of HTML5 and JavaScript can create applications through the use of languages ​​like PHP, Ruby, Python etc..
TideSDK is the new standard for creating beautiful and unique desktop apps using your web development skills.

You should try it

[Home of Tide](http://www.tidesdk.org/)

Comment: Poor, poor, poor documentation! Tide has the worst docs I've ever seen. Nothing works based on their start documentation. Seems like someone with a messed up thoughts wrote the whole docs! The app and the process has way too many problems as of today!