# How to create .exe executable file for php project

Tags: php, yii, exe

I developed one project using YII framework. Now I want the project in single executable file.

Is it possible to create using yii or php libraries.

How to create .exe executable file for yii project.

And is it possible to convert project file to some format that if I install it any others

place that they can't read may be some encrypted format.

Comment: Is it supposed to launch a web server and your application?

Comment: Did you check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046675/convert-a-php-script-into-a-stand-alone-windows-executable ?

Comment: You can put it inside one .phar perhaps :)

Comment: is it possible to convert project file to some format that if I install it any others place that they can't read may be some encrypted format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: Not possible.

Long answer: It depends.

You could install a web- and database server on his machine (or create an installer that does it) and run the application locally on his machine.

or

You keep the application on a server and just provide a launcher that opens his browser and points it to the URL of the application.

It might be a good idea to switch to SQLite instead of MySQL but depending on how your application is written it might require a lot of code and SQL Query changes.

[PHP Desktop](http://code.google.com/p/phpdesktop/) which allows you to create desktop apps in the same way as you build websites with php/html/js.

The convenient solution is not to convert the website to .exe. I think it will be better if you have portable [server/php/mysql](http://portableapps.com/apps/development/xampp) and make the website work from a usb or CD with autorun.

Comment: Very good explanation vineet.

Answer (score 2):

there are many good options for the same and you can find them at [PHP Compilers](http://www.bing.com/search?q=PHP%20Compiler)

I have used [PHPLanger](http://www.php-compiler.net/doku.php) for the same

Comment: is it possible to create entire project to convert to a single file using PHPLanger

Comment: yes the entire project. please go through the documentation and try. If you face any problem we can work it out.