# How to Make .exe file for P.H.P. offline Application with Security

Tags: php, mysql, exe

I have shown this [Convert a PHP script into a stand-alone windows executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046675/convert-a-php-script-into-a-stand-alone-windows-executable) , but my problem is still remains :(

I have developed a Offline Application using `Core P.H.P.`, now I want to Sell it to my client, but my problem is that I don't want to allow Client can see my `Source code` or can access my Source code, they can run my application on their system but **cannot able to change the Code**.
If I made the .EXE of my application, **user cannot even copy my source code**, *if he/she had done this then it cannot remains useful for them*,

**AND ALSO THE MAIN THING IS I WANT A UNIQUE SECURITY FOR A PARTICULAR USER, EVERY USER SHOULD NOT HAVE THE SAME ACCESS KEY TO ACCESS THIS APPLICATION**

I have found this on GOOGLE and also on this SITE also,but still I didn't get my answer perfectly.

Actually I have no idea about this in `P.H.P`, If somebody found mistakes in my question then you are pleased to suggest me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046675/convert-a-php-script-into-a-stand-alone-windows-executable

Comment: Even if you "convert" or "compile" it to .exe you can always reverse engineer it. Also I think it would be fairly simple to do so. If you're afraid about them ripping your code host it yourself and ask for a monthly fee.

Comment: Just because you state what you want and scream a bit in caps and bold will not get this questions reopened. Show you have done research to all parts (obfuscation, license keys, generating one per client) and show you understand enough about it to do it yourself. Then if you have a programming-specific problem you cannot solve, ask a new question. The perfect answer to your question as you require may not be on the web; you are a developer to tie small working parts together in a larger problem-solving solution.

Comment: @Sagar I am not an owner nor a moderator, just somebody who sometimes has some spare time on his hands. I will not use that time to help people who are not willing to show what they have tried. Being a beginner does not keep you from reading about the subject and showing what you understand. Now your question just says _"I need a ready-made solution, pronto"_, which is not what this site is for. If anything you found does not solve your problem directly, does not mean you cannot use that solution at all. Name what you found and tell what you miss about it.

Comment: In this case there is no need to vote down this question, I am not harassing or disturbing you, then why you VOTED me down

Comment: i have tried (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046675/convert-a-php-script-into-a-stand-alone-windows-executable) this all web-sites trick and also downloaded this soft's, and also run this all, but i am not getting perfect answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**PHP LockIt**](http://www.phplockit.com/PhpLockIt_demo_installer_2_2_0.exe) Software. it will encode your code and your client can not modify your code.

Comment: I have use this software and it works well, but how many times I have to run this software ? I have many clients to buy this app.. Your answer is good, but not perfect

Comment: You can lock root folder.

Comment: @Sagar so any obfuscation software that doesn't support multi-user configurations out of the box you cannot use? Do you even want to program?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at hiphop php. A good and reliable 'compiler' for PHP

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HipHop_for_PHP

https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/

Comment: @Robert Podwika, I have found some solutions thank you

Answer (score 2):

Check ***Zend Guard***.

Zend Guard, the most widely accepted PHP encoding and obfuscation product on the market, protects your application from unlicensed use and reverse engineering.

- Prevent reverse engineering & unauthorized modifications
- Protect your code from unauthorized use
- Zend Optimizer and Zend Guard Loader - the free runtime decoders for Zend Guard

It's really good solution to protect your project.