# How to create Setup of Application that have made in PHP

Tags: php, exe

I am beginner for `PHP`, I have developed an Application in `PHP 5.3.9` and now I want to give it to my client, but the problem is I don't know how to make setup of that?

I have tried BAMCOMPILE for create `.exe` but BAMCOMPILE supports 4th version of `PHP` , and secondly I have about creating `.exe` using visual c++ but I couldn't understand it properly, Is anyone who knows solution for this?

Suggest me the proper way/steps I will go through them surely

Any help will be greatly appreciate

Comment: I'd take a look at this topic:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046675/convert-a-php-script-into-a-stand-alone-windows-executable

Comment: Why don't you set-up a server for the client?

Comment: What type of application is this? What I mean is just buy a server with PHP 5.3.9 support and put the app in a folder and that's it or is it a terminal application? I don't get why you need an exe if you're developing in PHP. I mean it seems possible but it defeats the purpose of using PHP in the first place.

Comment: @elclanrs ,  You are absolutely right, but my problem is, I want to give it to clients and i don't want to allow client access for using my code and not even to appear to them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [ExeOutput for Php](http://www.exeoutput.com/) software 
Applications made with ExeOutput for PHP run PHP scripts, PHP applications, and PHP websites natively, and do not require a web server, a web browser, or PHP distribution. They are stand-alone and work on any computer with recent Windows versions.