# Connect to SQL and display results in HTML from distributable package

Tags: asp.net, iis

I must apologise for the vagueness of this question, but I actually no idea of where my starting point should be here.

Among others, I know SQL & HTML/PHP/Javascript

I want to create a program that I can distribute amongst some peers which connects to a user-specified SQL server and generates a set of fixed reports. And I want my code (or a least the SQL) to be complied/hidden. I want this program to run on any Win 7+ client regardless of access to a local IIS or other server.

How I create an exe or other that runs a mini web server of sorts so that I can use PHP or even ASP/VB to connect to a SQL Server and display HTML reports in a web browser.

I know how to write what I need to access the server and build/display the reports, but I have no idea of where to start to make this work on a client machine without a webserver.

Any starting points to investigate will help me greatly.

Comment: Everything I need is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046675/convert-a-php-script-into-a-stand-alone-windows-executable/9046775#9046775