# Convert Php Project to exe

Tags: php

I have created one project in Php/Mysql .Now i want to create .exe file for this project.So that if anyone runs this exe file automatically mysql/php/apache get installed in other word he don't need to install anything.Is this Possible?

Thanks

Comment: Refer this    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046675/convert-a-php-script-into-a-stand-alone-windows-executable

Answer (score 3):

You need to learn to use the setup creators.. The [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) does the same by installing mysql and apache on the target computer. So your installer will be similar to WAMP that will silently install the apache and mysql and copy your files to www directory and create the database using some sql script.

Comment: how can i put my file in wamp.exe www directory.

Comment: If you are using wamp installer, then you have to manually place the files in www directory. But it you are creating your own installer, (for example, [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php)), then you can tell your installer to place files in www directory.