# How to convert Zend Framework Application into a windows executable standalone Software?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have Developed an application using Zend Framework . Now My Client is asking it to run as a **standalone software on Windows Platform** . I have tried [Convert a PHP script into a stand-alone windows executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046675/convert-a-php-script-into-a-stand-alone-windows-executable) Answer and solution is working well for Simple Php Scripts .

Is there any similar solution that can work fine with Zend Framework Project Application ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just deploy the application on a local webserver on the target desktop (I assume the client wants to be able to use the app without being online).

You can get the Zend Server CE installed on the client machine, and then just dump a copy of the application into the htdocs directory, and they can then access it locally at `http://localhost/`.

If, however, the client wants a truly native desktop application, then this is really the wrong tool for the job. You can knock in a nail with a screwdriver, but should you?

Answer (score 2):

Seriously, build a native application in a language like C++ using Qt then if you need to be cross platform or something else than php for a native desktop application. php is just the wrong tool for that task.