# I want to make php Application standalone

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, window

I want to make windows standalone app with php, even i want to use database, javascript in that application.

Note : i don't want to give source code to user.

I should be like exe file which user can run.

Answer (score 1):

If going with Windows, try [WinBinder](http://winbinder.org/). It allows you to develop native Windows applications using PHP.

It also supports SQLite, so you don't need a database server

Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046675/convert-a-php-script-into-a-stand-alone-windows-executable) will help you

Answer (score 0):

I use [phc](http://www.phpcompiler.org/) to create `.exe` files out of my PHP source code. It works quite well, but it's mostly good for console applications rather than full webpages.

However, you could have your PHP script include a basic "server" that allows the browser to communicate with it - I have done this in the past too, and while it might seem daunting the results were very rewarding.

Comment: **+1** for the answer. I didn't know this was possible with PHP.