# Can I create an windows exe application using PHP program and using Database also?

Tags: php

I am a college level student. From my school life I was very interested to website creating, and thats why I came to learn PHP language, now I'm able to create a PHP app in website, but I want to create an offline windows app using this language and Database.

But as I am student of college, CSE or Computer Engineering is not my textual study, thats why I cant learn Java or C/C++ anything other else.

So you profassional programmers, can you help me out?

Comment: For windows offline application I think it is better if you learn something like C#

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Here some ways for this:

- [Command Line PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php) — is for developing shell applications with PHP;
- [PHP Desktop](https://code.google.com/p/phpdesktop/) — is open source project for developing native
  desktop GUI applications using web technologies (PHP, HTML5,
  JavaScript & SQLite);
- [WinBinder](http://winbinder.org/) —  is a open source extension that allows PHP programmers to easily build native Windows applications;
- [Phalanger](http://www.php-compiler.net/) — is implementation of PHP, rewritten in C#. You can get access to C# libs;
- [ExeOutput](http://www.exeoutput.com/) — this makes it possible to create applications in native format for Windows with PHP, JavaScript and HTML;
- [PHP GTK](http://gtk.php.net/) — is an extension for the PHP programming language that implements language bindings for GTK+. But it is not supported from 2010;

Of course, maybe there are other ways, but **I recommend you for creating Windows apps use something like C++, Python, Java, C#, etc**. It's save your time and nerve.

Comment: I will give you an other that work`s very well https://sourceforge.net/projects/phpbrowserbox/?source=recommended. I have try the others that you say but my problem is that I want to make a single exe file with portable server binary files,an exe with the portable server inside,that execute the exe file to run portable server without extracting. Thank you!

Comment: There is `[wxPHP](https://github.com/wxphp/wxphp)` which I think is much cleaner and still in devlopment

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend you to learn c# or Java rather than using some PHP to Win projects. But answer is yes, You can look at this very good [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046675/convert-a-php-script-into-a-stand-alone-windows-executable%20stackoverflow%20post) which will probably answer your question or at least will give you a good starting point.