# Creating .exe program using PHP language?

Tags: php, windows, exe

My client is asking me to convert a PHP program into .exe format. I tried to convince him PHP is server side programming language but he is not accepting it. Is there any way to create a .exe program using PHP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046675/convert-a-php-script-into-a-stand-alone-windows-executable)

Comment: What does your PHP program do? There are utilities to compile PHP into Windows executables, as detailed in the answers to the question @Naruto linked to, but using them may or may not make sense for this specific use case. Either way, it sounds like you need a new client.

Comment: PHP can be executed locally very well, not only on a "server". Using it in the command line is perfectly fine - tell him it works like batch files / shell scripts do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute the exe file you can do by below command.

```
string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )
```

For more details you can visit this link:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

But, if you requirement is to create the exe file of php application it seems not a valid request, you can do following things to achive a work around:

1) Create the small VB application with Web component and set the URL in the web component as the application's http URL.
2) Create the setup file of the VB application.
3) When someone would install the exe file, at the end PHP application with http request only would open.