# Compile PHP code including cURL commands to exe file

Tags: php, curl, exe

Is it possible to create Windows exe file from PHP source which include cURLcommands? 
I want to create a portable program which works even on machines where PHP or cURL are not installed.

Actually I don't expect that it is possible to create just one executable file which don't need additional libraries. Even full cURL tools can be attached if it is needed.
Maybe I just want some way to join it after.

When I use some php to exe compiler like Phalanger etc, the compilation is successful but when I run the file it throws an error:

```
Error: Call to undefined function: 'curl_init' in C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\comm\comments.php on line 6, column 1.
```

Comment: This isn't really a programming related but [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046675/convert-a-php-script-into-a-stand-alone-windows-executable) are some good resources to turn .php -> .exe. Some of these programs will attach libraries onto your executable.

Comment: I have tried Phalanger, Bambalam and phc-win and I haven't found any solution.