# How can I restrict the access to my PHP source code?

Tags: php, mysql, executable

I know the question is kinda weird but the thing is like this:

I've created a web application in PHP and mySQL database for a school. And I am using the same application as the mini project for my semester. But now we need to submit the whole project into a DVD to my teacher.

But I don't want to give him my source code. What should I do now?

Is there any way such that I can restrict the access to my PHP code, (like for C++ project we can create executable file)

Comment: Depends, is the teacher grading your coding structure or just the performance/UI/UX?

Comment: I doubt you will win a Tony Award from the source code. What is the real issue?

Comment: @chris85 He has already given us grades.now he just needs my project.

Comment: You are taking about `complied` code, there isn't really a way to do that with PHP. Why not just share the code?

Comment: You are being graded on your programming skills. How do you expect your teacher to grade your project without being able to view it?

Comment: @duskwuff He has already given us grades.now he just needs my project.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to compile PHP files into an executable on Windows. I have only experimented with two of them, bamcompile and WinBinder. Bamcompile is a few years old, from personal experience doesn't work flawlessly, and I could not access their website, though found some old versions of it on SourceForge.

1. http://www.bambalam.se/bamcompile/
2. https://sourceforge.net/projects/bamcompile/files/bamcompile/

WinBinder on the other hand, is more intended to be used for making a GUI inside of PHP and therefore probably won't work with your current source code.

http://winbinder.org/

There appear to more options discussed here ([Convert a PHP script into a stand-alone windows executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046675/convert-a-php-script-into-a-stand-alone-windows-executable)), though I don't have experience with the other options and am not making any guarantees.

If I were you I'd just submit your source code to your teacher as is; I don't know the reason you don't want to share it with him, but if you really want to conceal your source code, the options above are the best free solutions. Wish you the best.

Answer (score 0):

I heard about ionCube and zendguard, they can create "compiled" code, but they are not free and should be installed on server.