# How to convert php (5.5 >7.0) project to exe file?

Tags: php, compilation, converters, exe

I have many files (`.php, .js, .css, .json, .html` e.t c...)

In my project (example Laravel project or default project without using framework) and how I can all project convert to a one `exe` file?

It is possible?

I seen **ZZEE PHPexe** but it not support `php 7`.

In general, there is software for converting the php code to a exe file from other versions of the php language (F.e `php 5.4, 5.5` or `5.6`)

Comment: Can you explain why you want it as an exe file?

Comment: Well, that he worked in `Windows` without a `web server` and in `offline mode`. @Nigel Ren

Comment: If you have PHP CLI installed, you can run it with the built in web server (http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php).

Comment: Simply without third-party additional programs it is impossible to start? For example, how does ZZEE PHPexe work? If we convert our file using this program, then how does it start? @Nigel Ren

Comment: From their web page - 'ZZEE PHPExe v 2.5 ships with PHP v 5.2.5' which sort of implies that if come with a copy of PHP.  I would also be very careful as the Javascript support seems to be hand crafted rather than fully blown.

Comment: i think ZZEE PHPexe will just launch your code (previously compiled with their tools) into a Windows application (which is just an internet explorer  and an internal webserver) and don't look to be update since a long time

Comment: did you catch this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046675/convert-a-php-script-into-a-stand-alone-windows-executable ?

Comment: Have you considered using a tool like Docker or Vagrant to create an environment for your code to run? (You can create an ubuntu environment and develop on that without having to change your os from windows). To clarify do you want to create a desktop app or do you want to test a web app?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at ExeOutput for PHP (https://www.exeoutput.com) , it's exactly what you need and it supports PHP 7. It creates one EXE, packs all files into the EXE and combined with a built-in server and Chromium-based viewer.

BTW ZZEE PHPExe is no more developed.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from ZZEE (which is pre-PHP5 or something) and ExeOutput (which is slow & creates a huge output), there are some command line tools that can do this job.

I'd give a try to **[RapidEXE](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Other-Programming-Files/RapidEXE.shtml)** (supports PHP 7.2)

Actually I never tried it with a Laravel project but in theory it can manage.
It's one of my latest products btw so I would love to hear any feedbacks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use docker container instead of exe