# Is there any way to convert Laravel app to stand alone desktop applications?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, exe

Is there any way to convert PHP or any Laravel Application to stand alone application for desktop. I mean is there any software to change our php code to desktop app?

Comment: I doubt it. There's electron for js apps but i don't think if you can find anything for php let alone laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actual truth is you can not make a `php` or `laravel` project into a standalone application in windows or any other os .

You can do this by using any browser or running it in local .

But there are alternative ways to do it .

There is a bridge between `php` and `.NET` . You can use peachpie to make it easy .

Link : 
http://www.peachpie.io

Peachpie is PHP 7 compiler based on Roslyn by Microsoft and drawing from popular Phalanger. It allows PHP to be executed within the .NET/.NETCore by compiling the PHP code to pure MSIL.

I suggest the above one . But for alternates, there are lot of resources available to do it .

For more :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9046775/8240120

Comment: you can make a php project into a standalone application - it's just a matter of converting the code - but 100% you can't use PHP to build a windows application (without any use of third-party tools)

Comment: @treyBake Yes!! You are right . That's what I have mentioned at the top of post