# AHK and PHP to EXE

Tags: php, compilation, exe, autohotkey, executable

I just created a tiny but useful project using *AutoHotKey* and *PHP*, and I would've like to distribute it for free on the internet.

The project is made using two files:

- `myproject.ahk` gets triggered when I press a specific shortcut, does some preliminary operations and then calls `myproject.php` using the *Run* command
- `myproject.php` takes some parameter from `myproject.ahk` from the command line and does some further operations such as a *cURL request*

I would like to distribute this project as an *executable file*, but I don't know how. Converting an *AHK* file to *EXE* is easy due to the integrated AutoHotKey GUI, while I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046675/convert-a-php-script-into-a-stand-alone-windows-executable) some online tools like [php-compiler.net](http://v4.php-compiler.net/) that can convert an interpreted language to a *binary file*.

But how to make a unique executable file? Should I build them separately and then merge them somehow?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might be possible to run the CURL directly from AHK using the [`LibCurl for AHK`](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=79127) library to bypass the need for the 2nd php script

Comment: Why not distribute the two files together as a bundle ? I think no one will mind to have an application containing more than one file.

Comment: @Spyre that's not for me... I do not just perform a cURL request using PHP but also some different operations which are difficult (if not impossible) using AHK. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @KenLee yeah, I could... But I've never seen something like this. Even if it is developed using many different languages, most of the program are distributed using a single executable file, or an `exe` and some `dll`s. I would like to learn how to do that.

Comment: If I were you I will put the main EXE in the application folder and then put the PHP's EXE in a subfolder under the application folder (say make the subfolder to have name such as support_files) so that it will not appear to be too ODD and the user will run the main EXE instead of the PHP's EXE file.

Comment: You might be able to do it with the built in Windows iexpress tool

Comment: @KenLee thank you very much! Could changing the file extension be a good idea (the file would work anyway since it is called from the command prompt)? What extension should I use in that case?

Comment: @Spyre good idea... let me try

Comment: @Spyre the Windows iExpress tool didn't work... It allows me to extract my files but keeps the two executables separate. I'm open to other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [FileInstall](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileInstall.htm). I have a similar need to yours and I *think* it's possible to include a `random.exe` into your `ahk.exe` as a resource and run without extracting to disk, but a couple of hours of googling "persuaded" me to use `FileInstall`, because the alternative will probably look like [this](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/87068-binrun-run-binary-executable-from-memory-eg-resource/?p=613267). Yeah, I don't know what I am looking at.

If you don't want to confuse your users with strange executables that appear out of nowhere, have your `php.exe` extracted to a temp folder.

```
FileInstall, % A_ScriptDir "\php.exe", % A_Temp "\php.exe", true
Run, % A_Temp "\php.exe " arg1 " " arg2
```